# Can "такое" work like a placeholder word referring to the following "когда" subordinate clause?

Tags: грамматика

I just said in conversation:

> Неужели у вас не бывает **такого**, **когда** вы просто не можете удержаться от улыбки?

Looking back on it, I'm not sure if  "такое" can work like a *placeholder* word referring to the following "когда" subordinate clause -- perhaps similar to the structure "стать **такой**, **как** ты", for instance.

How do native speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: In colloquial speech, it definitely can. If you drop **не** in front of **бывает**, you can also encounter `Неужели у вас бывает такоЕ, когда...`

Comment: @user75619 Hi. So how should my phrasing be paraphrased outside of colloquial speech?

Comment: You can add **ситуаций** in front of **когда** to say `Неужели у вас не бывает таких ситуаций, когда вы...?` Note that **такого** becomes **таких**. It may well be that even formal speech allows `... не бывает такого, когда...`, it's just that I can't vouch for it.

Comment: more often **такое** predominantly in Nominative and Genitive precedes subordinating conjunction **что**, i would say ***такого, что***, but your version isn't totally unidiomatic, Google knows 1320 instances of its occurance

Comment: and a more literary variant would have **так** instead of **такое** - ***не бывает так, что***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that it's perfectly acceptable in colloquial speech. However, a more commonly used construct is "такого, что":

> Неужели у вас не бывает **такого, что** вы просто не можете удержаться от улыбки?

Answer (score 0):

In phrases like

> У меня бывает **такое, что** я просыпаюсь рано утром и не могу больше
> заснуть.
> Бывает **такое, когда** хочешь сделать что-то хорошее, а не
> получается.
> Бывает **такое:** понимаешь, что знаком с человеком, а не
> можешь вспомнить имя.

the word такое is a placeholder. Pay attention, that the neuter gender is quite commonly used in such phrases of general meaning not containing a noun. Compare:

> Сейте разумное, доброе, вечное,
>
> Сейте! Спасибо вам скажет сердечное
>
> ‎Русский народ…
>
> Н.А.Некрасов

But **стать такой, как ты** means **to become like you**, and it can not only be shortened to **стать, как ты**, but also extended to **стать такой красивой** (**умной**, and also nouns **красавицей**, also phrases **хорошей мамой**), **как ты**. In this case такой is the Accusative case of **такая**, it's feminine. We can say **стать таким, как ты**, if we mean a man. Here the word **такой** is not a placeholder, the structure is different.

Answer (score 0):

Rosenthal et al., 210.3.а:

> … выбор союза или союзного слова, которые не подходят для данного контекста, например: … *Создалась обстановка, когда мало что благоприятствовало стабилизации* (слово *когда* с присущим ему значением времени не подходит для контекста; можно было сказать: *Создалась обстановка, которая не благоприятствовала стабилизации*)

It would be better to say:

> Неужели с вами не случается такого, что вы просто не можете удержаться от улыбки?

or

> Неужели у вас не бывает мгновения, когда вы просто не можете удержаться от улыбки?